# How do I use UI Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I've been searching on the internet how to use UI Bootstrap with AngularJS but I won't work.

This is my code right now:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="componenten/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="componenten/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="componenten/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!       </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleAnimation()">Toggle Animation ({{ animationsEnabled }})</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I already tried to add almost every script and css file but it will never work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include Angular Bootstrap as a dependency:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

And please delete the `ui-bootstrap.min.js` beacuse `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` contains both the code and template.

Comment: Okey that fixed a lot already, no more errors when I start the page but when I click a button I get errors again.

Comment: This is the error that is shown in the console "[$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/modal/window.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)"

Comment: Please remove the `ui-bootstrap.min.js` script tag. You only need the `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` one, which contains both code and templates.

Comment: I think you need to change the order in which you are loading the bootstrap JS files.

Comment: @SimoEndre no... you use one or the other...not both.